# Show that a connected simple graph for which every edge is in some perfect matching is a block

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, graph-connectivity

> Show that a connected simple graph for which every edge is in some perfect matching is a block.

It seems obvious to prove by contradiction. so Suppose such a graph $G$ has a cut-vertex $v$.

The direction from here seems to be taking two components $H_1, H_2$ of $G-v$, and let $e_1, e_2$ be the edges by which $v$ was connected to those respectively.$e_1$ and $e_2$ are both in some perfect matchings in $G$, but they must be different matchings since they share a vertex. Call them $M_1, M_2$. How to continue from here? I'm guessing I'm looking for some contradiction to arise when looking at $M_1\cap E(H_2)$ or vice versa, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: I don't think you should say that your question is a possible duplicate of that link, when it does not appear to be (in my opinion).  However, it depends on what you mean by "blocks."  With the definition of block graphs I know, your statement is false (as a $4$-cycle graph is not a block graph, but it satisfies the required condition).  So, if "block" means "$2$-vertex-connected," then yes, this thread is a duplicate.  For the definition of block graphs, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_graph.

Comment: By block i mean "A maximal 2-vertex-connected subgraph", so saying a graph is a block is just saying it is 2-vertex-connected. And the solution in the other thread works for me.

Comment: OK, then, yes, this is indeed a duplicate.  Thanks for the clarification.  (By the way, is it usual to refer to "a maximal $2$-vertex-connected subgraph" as a block?  I never heard of this.)

Comment: That's the definition in Douglas B. West's Introduction to Graph Theory which I'm learning from. It generally seems it doesn't have the generally accepted definitions and symbols. Had a trouble with this in another question on this site

Comment: Actually, the first paragraph in the Wikipedia article you linked has "... in which every biconnected component (block) is a ..."

Comment: I missed that, but then, I never referred or heard anybody use the term block for biconnected component.  This is news to me.